# sudo apt-get upgrade "encouters error while processing" in basically everything

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 20.04, dpkg

04.1 as a dual boot with GRUB. I was installing openFOAM and then I tried to upgrade packages using the usual `sudo apt-get upgrade` but I keep getting errors for standard packages.
This is the output of the `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]    
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [229 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [202 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [12.3 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,768 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.3 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [55.6 kB]
Hit:3 https://sourceforge.net/projects/openfoam/files/repos/deb focal InRelease
Fetched 844 kB in 3s (293 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

and here is the output of the `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,441 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mutter:
 mutter depends on adwaita-icon-theme; however:
  Package adwaita-icon-theme is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mutter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depends on mutter (>= 3.36.0); however:
  Package mutter is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibus:
 ibus depends on adwaita-icon-theme; however:
  Package adwaita-icon-theme is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ibus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdm3:
 gdm3 depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmutter-6-0:amd64:
 libmutter-6-0:amd64 depends on adwaita-icon-theme; however:
  Package adwaita-icon-theme is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libmutter-6-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gdm3; however:
  Package gdm3 is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gnome-shell; however:
  Package gnome-sheNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                       ll is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64:
 gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 depends on libmutter-6-0 (= 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2); however:
  Package libmutter-6-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons:
 gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.33); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop-minimal:
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal depends on gdm3; however:
  Package gdm3 is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal depends on gnome-shell; however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons; however:
  Package gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libgtk-3-0:amd64:
 libgtk-3-0:amd64 depends on adwaita-icon-theme; however:
  Package adwaita-icon-theme is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgtk-3-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libgtk2.0-0:amd64:
 libgtk2.0-0:amd64 depends on adwaita-icon-theme | gnome-icon-theme; however:
  Package adwaita-icon-theme is not installed.
  Package gnome-icon-theme is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 mutter
 gnome-shell
 ibus
 gdm3
 libmutter-6-0:amd64
 ubuntu-desktop
 gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64
 gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal
 libgtk-3-0:amd64
 libgtk2.0-0:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried to follow [this tutorial](https://journalxtra.com/linux/fixing-the-dreaded-errors-were-encountered-while-processing-errors/) and remove each package individually and reinstall them but I am not able to remove them as they are other packages depend on them. Also it says that `adwaita-icon-theme` is not installed but when I try to install it its says it already exists. What would be the best method of attack? I do not have alot of data on it so i would be able to wipe the drive and reinstall ubuntu if that's easier. Thanks.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt because its not apparent to me. What am I missing?

Comment: @elphmatt Not entirely sure if I am honest, I am never good with dpkg and aptitude problems. Also not quite sure why my comment was removed. My question still stands to Nmath though. I am not sure why forums would even exist if solutions were so apparent just by reading verbose logs. There are plenty of examples on this site alone of problems that really have no simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar error and the problem was the code version of ubuntu.
Please check your `sources.list` files. All should have the same code version.

Run this command to get the version:

```bsh
lsb_release -c
```

Te outputs should be something like:

```
Codename:       focal
```

*You will see your code instead of focal*

Next use this command to see all your deb entries:

```bsh
find /etc/apt -iname '*.list' -exec awk '$1 ~ /^deb/ {print}' {} \;
```

and check if the code of `lsb_release` is the same of your deb entries.

*Note: there are sofware repositories that don't use codes for example opera browser, wich use `stable` code.*

Comment: Sorry what am I comparing the output of `find /etc/apt -iname '*.list' -exec awk '$1 ~ /^deb/ {print}' {} \;` to?

Comment: you should see the code version in the repos, for example in `deb http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted multiverse universe` the code is **focal**, that match with `lsb_release` output.

Comment: Ok thanks. It looks like all of the repos have the code focal and match the output of `lsb_release -c`

Comment: Then try with `apt install -f` and `dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: I ran those and they just gives the same errors as the `sudo apt-get upgrade`.